# get parent a clicked modal in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a table that has many rows.

every `tr` tag in my table have `data-id` attribute.
and have some `td` inside and the `td` have `button` for show modal with bootstrap.

my table like this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table">
                <tbody>
               <tr data-id="1">
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>phone</td>
                    <td><button class="call-list btn btn-primary calls" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".calls">calls</button></td>
                    <td><button class="call-add btn btn-success porsuits" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".pursuits">pursuit</button></td>
                  
               </tr>
             
               <tr data-id="1">
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>phone</td>
                    <td><button class="call-list btn btn-primary calls" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".calls">calls</button></td>
                    <td><button class="call-add btn btn-success porsuits" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".pursuits">pursuit</button></td>
                   
               </tr>
             
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

i want to get `data-id` in tr parent of the `buttons` in my table with jquery

i try some code but all of them get the class of target modal path

i try this code

```js
   getDataSrc('.calls', 'data-src');

    function getDataSrc(target, attr){
      $(target).click(function(){
        var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr(attr);
        alert(id);
      });

    }
```

Comment: _Show us_ what you tried.

Comment: you want the id on the button click ?

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: no i want this happen by class

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').data('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
                <tbody>
               <tr data-id="1">
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>phone</td>
                    <td><button class="call-list btn btn-primary calls" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".calls">calls</button></td>
                    <td><button class="call-add btn btn-success porsuits" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".pursuits">pursuit</button></td>
                  
               </tr>
             
               <tr data-id="2">
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>phone</td>
                    <td><button class="call-list btn btn-primary calls" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".calls">calls</button></td>
                    <td><button class="call-add btn btn-success porsuits" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".pursuits">pursuit</button></td>
                   
               </tr>
             
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

This code will return you in console the id of the clicked element

Comment: the code is working fine, what do yo mean with "not working"? _i want to get data-id in tr parent of the buttons in my table with jquery_ and that is what you get in the id variable. What is wrong with that?

Comment: when i click the button the modal opening and logging nothing

Comment: this code returns you just the id of the tr. It does nothing on any modal at all. There is no modal at all in your question btw.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function for button click, and from that function, you can access the parent dom  for each  using jQuery and also open bootstrap model.

```
function clickHandle(elm) {
    alert($(elm).closest("tr"));
}
```